# 错误 XFC0000 Cannot resolve type "clr-namespace: ToolsMiniHub.Views:FontIcons"

Tags: xaml, maui

I have already added this static class to point to my font, but it always fails to resolve. I also created another static class file, changed to a different namespace and class name, but it still doesn't work. Of course, I've tried cleaning the solution and recompiling, but it seems that no matter what, the static class cannot be resolved in the XAML file.

[image]
[image]
[image]

how can i resolve this problem

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  Code should never be posted as images